# How to ignore messages from the client in a wait_for_message() function?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I`m trying to do a hangman game, but the problem is that the client just takes his own message as a message. How can I get the wait for message to only accept input from some users?

Here's my code so far:

```
@client.command()
async def hangman():
    guess = ""
    hp = 6
    word = "Banana"
    slot = slotMaker(word, guess)
    await client.say("Let`s play the hangman! \n The word is a fruit \n" + slot)
    while slot != word and hp > 0:
        guess += client.wait_for_message()
        slot = slotMaker(word, guess)
        await client.say(slot)
        if letterChecker(word, guess):
            pass
        else:
            hp -= 1
            await client.say("Your hp is now " + str(hp) + ".")
```

Edit: These are the messages sent in the discord channel:

```
Esdver9000Today at 11:58 PM
!hangman
sawg112BOTToday at 11:58 PM
Let`s play the hangman! 
 The word is a fruit 
------
-anana
Your hp is now 5.
-anana
Your hp is now 4.
-anana
Your hp is now 3.
-anana
Your hp is now 2.
-anana
Your hp is now 1.
-anana
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) has an optional `author` argument, which you can use to accept messages from the person who invoked the command. You should likely also provide a `channel` argument, so you don't use messages that user sends in other channels.

```
msg = await client.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)
```

If you want to accept messages from any user that is not the `client`, you could write a `check` for `wait_for_message` like:

```
check = lambda message: message.author != client.user
msg = await client.wait_for_message(check=check)
```